# Посчитать частоту появления каждого слова в строке

Tags: c

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно посчитать частоту каждого слова на языке C?

Например строка: "rtr yjh we rtr"

Вывод:

rtr 2

yjr 1

we 1

Большое спасибо за любые советы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055525/frequency-of-every-word-in-a-string Используйте поиск

Comment: Решение подобной задачи. https://pastebin.com/vsQG1bPS

Answer (score 1):

Если это учебная задачка и не требуется серьёзная оптимизация, то тогда алгоритм должен быть такой: заведи массив структур. Структура будет содержать указатель на char (тут будет хранится сама строка) и частоту появления слова. Парси каждое слово. Для каждого слова линейным поиском (самым простым) просматривай созданный массив. Если слово уже встречалось - прибавляй +1 к частоте, если не встречалось, то динамически выдели место под строку, скопируй туда слово, указатель на эту память запиши в поле со строкой и установи частоту в 1. И так далее....

Можешь запариться и реализовать более сложную структуру данных и более быстрый поиск.

Используемые структуры данных (для 100 разных слов):

```
struct Word_Data {
    char *word;
    int frequency;
}

struct Word_Data words[100];
```